# Certificate management: private key distribution with Netflix Lemur framework

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, key-management

My team has had some challenges with our current internal PKI management tools and we are looking for other solutions.  One of my team members forwarded me a link to a page about [Lemur](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/introducing-lemur-ceae8830f621), an open source framework from Netflix.

It's a pretty well written article and most of what is discussed seems relevant to struggles I've seen and experienced but there's one thing that I'm confused about.

The following diagram is meant to show "a typical procurement process".

[image]

What I would typically do is generate a new key-pair on the host using something like the [Java keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html).  This generates the key and stores it in the keystore.  Then a CSR is created and signed by the CA.  The signed cert is then imported back into the store.  I think this diagram can be interpreted to describe this process but it doesn't clearly show that the private key never leaves the 'deployment target'.

The proposed new procurement process looks like this:

[image]

Now, it would seem from the diagram, that the private key is generated on a separate server and then delivered (presumably via secure means) to the 'deployment target'.

The ability to generate a CSR and get the public key signed without needing to move a private key around seems pretty slick to me.  I thought it was designed this way for a reason.  While I can see the advantages from a convenience perspective, isn't this approach of pushing private keys inherently adding more risk of private key exposure?

The text of the article says that it can support certificates generated elsewhere which but implies that this is to help transition to using Lemur to generate them.  I'm not convinced that is a step forward.  Am I missing something?

Comment: The difference is Lemur does the CSR generation and sending the keys to the deployment target bit for the developer and handles the CSR approval bit for the Security Engineer thereby removing unnecessary manual steps in the process, especially as the developer may not get all the extensions correct on the initial CSR. In either case, the deployment machine needs the private key to perform key exchange and sign messages so one needs a way to put it on there securely anyway. In both cases in diagram that is only an intermediary, I guess Lemur has secret key storage built in.

Comment: @ewanm89 "so one needs a way to put it on there securely anyway" I'm not sure I follow.  Using the standard approach, the key is generated on the deployment server and stored there securely.  There's no need to 'put' it there, if 'put' means deliver it over the network.

Comment: Except Netflix have a whole load of load balancers, applications servers, database servers, storage servers all needing certs then a whole separate development network. At the scale Netflix operates at, copying the private key from one machine to another will have to happen at some point. As the answer pointed out this is not for individual machines and this is for when one has a secure network to operate with.

Comment: "Netflix have a whole load of load balancers, applications servers, database servers, storage servers all needing certs"  So does my employer.  The scale is different, to be sure but I don't see why the scale must require that "copying the private key from one machine to another will have to happen at some point".

Comment: @JimmyJames So you have multiple instances of the webserver host all using the same TLS certificate, but you have never copied the private key? How exactly?

Comment: @MikeOunsworth I don't know where you are getting that the hosts are all using the same certificate.  Can you elaborate on why that is your assumption?

Comment: Because in the previous comment you said "Netflix have a whole load of load balancers... So does my employer". A load balancer implies that any of the servers behind it can respond to any of the incoming requests, which implies they are all serving the same content with the same certificate. I suppose you could go and get one cert per server, all with the same DN and SANs, but all cloud deployments I've seen get one cert and replicate it across all the load-balanced hosts (or has the load balancer(s) terminate the TLS connections).

Comment: Typically, there's a certificate on the load balancer and then one on the server.  There's termination at the load balancer and then at the server.  If we do client-certs, we can't do that so it get's a little more complicated.  If you want the load balancer to be able to monitor the traffic, then you need to have the private key there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, that's how I would read that too.

I assume that for a large cloud-based company like Netflix, the Lemur server would be part of their virtualized prod environment cluster and therefore held to the same level of network security as everything else in the prod environment. For example, if the deployment target is actually a cluster of VM hosts behind a load-balancer (or the load-balancer itself is terminating the TLS connections) then some amount of private key copying will be happening anyways and they'll have infrastructure to handle that properly. Adding a Lemur server to the cluster doesn't open any additional attack surface beyond what's already inherent to a large cloud deployment.

For smaller deployments where your prod server is a single machine, then I think your concerns are justified and it's worth asking some questions about additional copies of the private key floating around.

Comment: "therefore held to the same level of network security as everything else in the prod environment": I guess I was reading from a perspective that perimeter security is bunk and that we need to assume we have internal threats.  This approach would appear to create a situation where the comprise of a single server would compromise every private key used.  I'm not sure if that qualifies as increasing the attack surface but it's seems undesirable.

Comment: I probably should ask the team directly and/or look into the details of the design but why not build the solution upon the existing CSR approach.  If the deployment target can accept a key-pair from lemur, surely it can accept a 'generate a new pair and return a CSR' request followed by a 'here's a signed certificate' request.

Comment: _"This approach would appear to create a situation where the comprise of a single server would compromise every private key used."_ Sure, but presumably a compromised admin account already has access to the key files on all servers. That seems like a very similar attack surface. On the other hand, if you're separating your prod servers into different admin groups so that no single admin has access to all of them, then you probably want separate instances of Lemur to match.

Comment: OK, I see where you are going but it's not necessary to have the admin account credentials to be able to compromise the application and/or server.  For example, a remote code execution exploit might allow for passively capturing private keys and pushing them to an accessible location.

Comment: @JimmyJames how you do you a remote code execution on the Lemur server with to publicly-accessible ports?

Comment: How would it have a web interface and a REST API without publicly accessible ports?

Comment: Just to make sure we're talking about the same thing: I'm imagining the Lemur server would have a REST API that's accessible _only_ from other hosts inside the prod subnet. That's not "public". Whereas the webservers will have HTTP/S ports that are accessible to the public internet. To compromise the Lemur server, you already need to be inside the prod network.

Comment: As I stated, I'm coming from the perspective that perimeter security is bunk.

Comment: Alright, so you've compromised the perimeter network. Do the admin credentials that work on one instance of the prod server(s) also work on all other instances? In that case it really doesn't matter if the private keys are all in one file, or the attacker needs to spend trivially more effort to go fetch them from each server. If servers are split into multiple security groups with non-overlapping admin credentials, then yeah, you'll need one Lemur instance per security group.

Comment: You don't need to be admin to be on the network.  If everyone on the network is an admin, you have bigger problems.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase .. "Do the same credentials that get you access to the TLS private key on one instance of the prod server(s) also get you access to the TLS private key on all instances?". ie once inside the network, is compromising one server equivalent to compromising all servers?

Comment: Sure let's go with that.  Lemur creates the possibility of accessing all keys that it services without needing admin access to anything.

Comment: I've never used Lemur, but I'd be highly surprised if there's a way to extract all private keys from Lemur's keystore with no authentication at all. Can you back up that claim?

Comment: I kind of feel like we are going in circles here.  For example, a remote code execution exploit might allow for passively capturing private keys and pushing them to an accessible location.  There are many ways to exploit vulnerabilities that have nothing to do with compromising admin accounts.

Comment: Right, what I don't understand about that example is how exploiting an RCE vuln against the Lemur server to get all the private keys is any different from exploiting an RCE vuln against each of the identical prod servers to get all the private keys.

Comment: Our applications do not run with the credentials required to export the private key.  They run under an account with limited rights and they don't have the password for exporting the private key.  The lemur runtime (if I understand it correctly) is generating and managing the private keys and therefore inherently must have access to them.  This is in addition to any risk you already have on your actual application (not lemur) which would seem to be increasing the attack surface, no?

Comment: If you go to the [admin docs](http://lemur.readthedocs.io/en/latest/administration.html) It has this under `DEBUG`: "Warning This should never be used in a production environment as it exposes Lemur to remote code execution through the debug console."

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Our applications do not run with the credentials required to export the private key"? Do you mean that your internet-facing public keys can load the TLS private key into memory and use it, but somehow need a password to dump that memory to a file? If you mean that your applications use private keys in HSMs or hardware tokens, then the question becomes whether Lemur supports HSM-based keys, which is an entirely different question.

Comment: LOL - the docs tell you not to turn on Lemur's debug mode on a prod server, and therefore don't use Lemur? For comparison, the JSSE (java's TLS implementation) also has a debug mode that dumps TLS session keys to a log file. Does that mean I should never use java in a production application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69402/discussion-between-jimmyjames-and-mike-ounsworth).

Answer (score 1):

Generally in the past Netflix has communicated that they deploy baked AMIs (VM images) of their code, which are stripped down to exactly what they need. This usually also means they are using an autoscaling group in Amazon that get spun up as they require. This is changing with containers but the same general principal holds. [1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiLjrqL55bYAhVTwWMKHbrDBkQQFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftechblog.netflix.com%2F2016%2F03%2Fhow-we-build-code-at-netflix.html&usg=AOvVaw1WUE_O507M50JSpv5wC_DK)

This usually has one major implication for secrets like private keys. You aren't generating them on the host that will run your service & you do not bake the secrets into the application artifact. You pull them down at runtime or they are loaded onto a load balancer.

Second bit that I think Lemur has in mind and another product called Vault from HashiCorp pushes heavily is that you centralize where you generate/store secrets so you have a limited spread of where they are. It also means that you aren't baking extra stuff for cert generation into your production images. It does mean you probably have a few juicy targets, but the gist I've been seeing from a lot of these players is that it is easier to centrally protect a few things segregated by blast radius than to poorly protect hundreds or thousands of things. Usually this goes had in hand with shorter lived secrets so if/when things get compromised you just change it out and you have practice in doing it so the damage is limited.

Comment: "centralize where you generate/store secrets so you have a limited spread of where they are" at a high level, I think that makes sense but in order to be used, these need to be distributed to the hosts that use them.  It would seem to me that you are adding a juicy target and but not really limiting where they are.  You also add a distribution step which adds more risk.  I'm over-simplifying this though.  If you are more concerned with a compromised host being used to generate a key that is then signed, I can see how centralizing this fits into the model you describe.

Comment: The other half I failed to mention of the centralization step for HashiCorp at least is that you do not have long lived certificates, they are constantly rotating so that even if a certificate or private key get compromised they have a very limited lifetime. We're talking days or a week at max.